# How to parse org-mode by org-element elegantly

Tags: parsing, emacs, org-mode

`org-element` is a new module for `org-mode`, I think it is good for parse org file, and don't want to parse it by old way with match-string. but after play with it for some hours, I have to admit I don't have enough experience with org-mode, so could masters give me some clues, thanks very much!

My requirement is simple, I want to get all headlines and content.

```
* headline

:PROPERTIES

** subheadline

content1

** subheadline

content2
```

Comment: What's the requirement in fact ?
something like
     (let ((parsetree (org-element-parse-buffer 'headline)))
      (org-element-map parsetree 'headline (lambda (hl)
                                             (org-element-property :title hl))))
would get you titles for all headlines.

Comment: thanks, then how to get the content of one headline?

Comment: The requirement is still not completely clear to me. Let's say you have code blocks in your document, is that meant to be part of the content ? what about tables ? It could be also that what you want is simply an org-to-text exporter.

Comment: yes, I want extract headline, subheadline, content separately. it means fun1() return all headline, fun2(headline) return its subheadline, fun3(subheadline) return its content.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

based on @YoungFrog's prompt:

- get all headlines:

  ```
  (let ((parsetree (org-element-parse-buffer 'headline))) 
    (org-element-map parsetree 'headline 
                     (lambda (hl) (org-element-property :title hl))))
  ```
- get all contents:

  ```
  (let ((parsetree (org-element-parse-buffer 'paragraph)))
    (org-element-map parsetree 'paragraph 
                     (lambda (hl) (org-element-interpret-data hl))))
  ```

Comment: Using OP's MWE, the code to get all contents does not work for Org 9.4. Can you update the code ?